# Running npm install in a Visual Studio project's post-build event

Tags: npm, tfs, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019, post-build-event

In my project's post-build event, I have 2 tasks--run `npm install` and then run a gulpfile.

I'm using Azure DevOps and in my build pipeline, when `npm install` is run within my project's post-build event, it only runs the `npm install` command and not the gulpfile. It outputs:

[image]

However, if I run a `npm install` task (pointing directly to my `package.json`) prior to the `npm install` being run in my project's post-build event, then the gulpfile does get run.

I'm wondering what the issue could be here? Is it because I'm not specifying the `package.json` in my post-build event?

My post-build event script looks like this:

```
npm install
node.exe "node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js" --gulpfile "gulpfile.js"
```

Comment: Can you add to your question how you have defined post build event?

Comment: Why you have to put your npm install in a post-build event? We usually use this in the top of a pipeline only after get source code from repo. It's much easier to use.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT the main reason I'm doing this is so that my Azure DevOps build pipelines only worry about packaging and uploading the build artifact. We could have put the npm install and the gulp portion into our build pipeline. But I want to consolidate how the package is built on a dev machine and how the package is built on a build agent for deployment. At a higher level, I don't want the build agent to have to know about the details of our project (i.e. it needs to run an npm install, or it needs to run a gulpfile, etc.)--I just want it to package and upload the build artifact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that calling `npm install` directly within in the post-build event script stops the parent batch program. The way to fix this is to use the command `call`, documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/call). That is, use `call npm install`.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly sharing. You could *mark your reply as an answer*, which will also helps others in the community.